# Postgresql: tsvector full text search

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing 100m rows and i need to full text search it
and provide information about how similar (e.g. with the `pg_trgm` module)
the text's are. Off cause the problem here is that it should be fast.

I tried gist and gin indexes, had a extra column with the tsvector of my field etc.

My idea is to query first using tsvector and after that running the similarity function provided by the `pg_trgm` module.

My problem is the following. If i use a whole word as my query it will work. But not if i append something.

This makes total sense because the tsvector of "A quick brown fox..." is 
`"'a':1 'brown':3 'fox':4 'quick':2"`.

I hope i made clear what i would like to achieve.

### Example:

#### works

```
select to_tsvector('A quick brown fox...') @@ to_tsquery('quick') -- true
```

#### does not work

```
select to_tsvector('A quick brown fox...') @@ to_tsquery('quicks') -- false
```

Any ideas on how to achieve that using postgresql?

Comment: What version of Postgres is that? Second query gives me true on 9.6.2
EDIT: Oh, checked on 9.6.5 and indeed it works as you described.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński that depends on the dictionary. I get true by default with the "english" dictionary, false if I explicitly use the "simple" dictionary in to_tsquery. This is due to stemming, I think, which would remove the s, but won't just remove any arbitrary characters at the end.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I got PostgreSQL 9.6.2

Comment: @MadScientist indeed. I tried with `to_tsquery('english', 'quicks')` and get true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the language configuration parameter, like this:

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'A quick brown fox...') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'quicks')
```

The capability to recognize lexemes correctly, with plurals and stuff only happens when `tsquery` and `tsvector` have the same language configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When performing a full-text search using tsvector and tsquery in PostgreSQL, it is practical to use the same configuration for both the tsvector and tsquery. This can be achieved by identifying the value of the configuration and using it consistently throughout the application.
Assuming a table with millions of rows, you can add an extra column to represent the tsvector rows with configurations for each tsvector. You can then use a GIN index to represent the configurations. When using the @@ parameter to search for keywords in the tsvector column, it is mandatory to specify the configuration since there is no default value accepted in the index configuration. Each tsvector may have a different configuration, so it is important to use the correct configuration when performing the search.
this is can be seen as a toknizations is different than lemmatization the second only achieved given the two constrains
with to_tsquery and setting the same config for both the tsvector and the given query